# Silverlight ListBoxDragDropTarget not accepting Drop

Tags: silverlight, listbox, drag

In the XAML attached you will see a listbox.  When the ItemsSource property that is it bound to (in a viewmodel) is empty, the DragDrop action appears to be available (the dragging cursor shows it can be dropped).  The problem is once the ListBox becomes bound, it no longer accepts drops.  I can see that my control will accept drops if I get my cursor into the space between the listbox and the edge of the control, so it is clearly something with the listbox.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverWare.Avrio.Presentation.Silverlight.Controls.MenuPanelDesigner"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:SilverWare.Avrio.Presentation.Silverlight.ValueConverters"
xmlns:controlToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="500"
MouseLeftButtonUp="MenuPanelDesigner_MouseLeftButtonUp"
MouseMove="MenuPanelDesigner_MouseMoved"
LostMouseCapture="MenuPanelDesigner_LostMouseCapture"
DataContext="{Binding MenuLayoutDesigner, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" AllowDrop="True">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PanelButtonContainerTemplate">
        <Border RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" MouseLeftButtonDown="MenuPanelDesigner_MouseLeftButtonDown" Width="{Binding PanelButton.DTO.Width}" Height="{Binding PanelButton.DTO.Height}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PanelButton.DefaultLabel}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Margin="-4" Background="{Binding SelectedMenuGroup.Panel.BackColorBrush}" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" Grid.Column="1" AllowDrop="True" />
    <controlToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget Grid.Column="1" AllowDrop="True">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMenuGroup.MenuGroupItems}" Width="495" Height="625" Background="Transparent" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanelButtonContainerTemplate}" x:Name="lstMenuItems" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
                 SelectionMode="Extended" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuGroupItem, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowDrop="True">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas AllowDrop="True" />   
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding PanelButton.DTO.Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding PanelButton.DTO.X, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding PanelButton.DTO.Width, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding PanelButton.DTO.Height, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </controlToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding AddItem}" Content="Add Item" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the `controlToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget` does not Drag and Drop when the underlying `ListBox`'s background is transparent. Change the background to something else and it should work just fine.